# Process not detected in whitelist

Tags: arrays, vb.net, process

I got a problem in my code. I want to make a process whitelist and kill processes not on the list. However, the code below doesn't work. Help me please. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub killProcess()
Dim processWhitelist() As string = {"calc", "notepad", "explorer"}
Dim pathWhitelist() As String = {"C:\Users\G83394\Desktop\Personal", "C:\Program Files", "C:\Windows\System32", "C:"}
For Each proc In Process.GetProcesses
    Try

        For Each path As String In pathWhitelist
            If proc.mainmodule.filename.contains(path) Then
                For Each p In processWhitelist
                    If proc.processname.contains(p) Then
                        MsgBox(proc.processname & " is found in whitelist.")
                    end if
                Next

            Else
                MsgBox(proc.processname & " is NOT found in whitelist.")
            End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be getting "Access Denied" Error with `proc.mainmodule.filename`. This may be due to Platform Target 64-bit/32-bit issue or due to Restricted Access Privilege.

> Though, You can use WMI to get the path. Make a reference to the
>   `System.Management.dll` assembly and use the `System.Management`
>   namespace. You can query the process with ManagementObjectSearcher.

```
Private Sub killProcess()
        Dim processWhitelist() As String = {"calc", "notepad", "explorer"}
        Dim pathWhitelist() As String = {"C:\Users\G83394\Desktop\Personal", "C:\Program Files", "C:\Windows\System32", "C:"}
        For Each proc In Process.GetProcesses
            Dim s1 = GetMainModuleFilepath(proc.Id)
            If Not IsNothing(s1) AndAlso pathWhitelist.Any(Function(s) s1.StartsWith(s)) Then
                If processWhitelist.Contains(proc.ProcessName) Then
                    MsgBox(proc.ProcessName & " is found in whitelist.")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox(proc.ProcessName & " is NOT found in whitelist.")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetMainModuleFilepath(processId As Integer) As String
        Dim wmiQueryString As String = "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " & processId
        Using searcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString)
            Using results = searcher.[Get]()
                Dim mo As ManagementObject = results.Cast(Of ManagementObject)().FirstOrDefault()
                If mo IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return DirectCast(mo("ExecutablePath"), String)
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Also use LINQ to process lists or arrays, Using `proc.processname.contains(p)` is not a proper way to compare.

Refer [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Noted. I'll try this when I get home in Visual Studio Express. What I have here is Sharp Develop and it gives me errors in spite of adding reference to System.Management namespace. Thanks :)

Comment: Its working! :) But system processes returns empty path but I think this due to access restrictions. Anyway, Im just intercepting user-launhed processes so not a problem to me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ashish, I dont understand why your code consumes more cpu cycles, sometimes at 30%. Please help.